# Unable to decompress the obb file in JOBB

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compression

i have an `.obb` file and i tried to decompress it using JOBB provided by sdk, it's giving me an error

### Here is what i tried

```
./jobb -d ./file.obb -o ./output-folder -pn obbdec -pv 110336
```

### Error i'm getting

```
Slop: 0   Directory Overhead: 0
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.base/java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:101)
    at com.android.jobb.Main$2.processFile(Main.java:554)
    at com.android.jobb.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:604)
    at com.android.jobb.Main.getTotalFileSize(Main.java:544)
    at com.android.jobb.Main.main(Main.java:379)
```

What i'm doing wrong ??